# How to get drive info from the solaris commandline for veritas netbackup

Tags: command-line-interface, netbackup, veritas

We use Veritas Netbackup to control our L180 tape robot at $WORK, but I'm getting some weird results from the GUI. So in the age old struggle for truth.. it's back to the commandline.

Unfortunately, I can't work out how to pull the info I need.  Can anyone give me the magic incantation to check the drive diagnostics from the commandline? (Solaris 8, Netbackup 6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/usr/openv/volmgr/vmoprcmd -d ds
```

Should show you the Drives or to a bit low level.

```
/usr/openv/volmgr/sgscan all
```

Should show you all the attached drives.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the StorageTeks, but on our Tandberg, we need to use Tandberg supplied utilities to get diagnostics from the robot.  The built in Veritas diagnostics always fail...